# Fetching from in-memory database not working

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, effort

I started to use Effort for unit testing.

Here is my code for initialization:

```
    private IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void SetupTest()
    {
        DbConnection connection = Effort.DbConnectionFactory.CreateTransient();

        var context = new STContext(connection);

        context.Fakturas.Add(new Faktura { ID = 1, FakturaNo = 1000, OwnerID = 1 });
        context.Fakturas.Add(new Faktura { ID = 2, FakturaNo = 1001, OwnerID = 1 });

        context.Products.Add(new Product { ID = 1, Name = "ProductA", Price = 50 });
        context.Products.Add(new Product { ID = 2, Name = "ProductB", Price = 100 });

        context.Orders.Add(new Order { ID = 1, FakturaID = 1, ProductID = 1, Quantity = 1 });
        context.Orders.Add(new Order { ID = 2, FakturaID = 2, ProductID = 1, Quantity = 1 });

        unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(context);
    }
```

Then when I debug test I can see in debugger that those values from the code above are there, they are inserted in in-memory database, but fetching queries don't return them. Here is the image from debugger: [image]

This is one of the queries which returns 0 elements `return unitOfWork.Context.Products.ToList();`

Anyone knows what might cause the problem?

UPDATE: This code passes: `return unitOfWork.Context.Products.Local.ToList<Product>();`

UPDATE 2: I solved it. Saving changes was missing in `SetupTest` method:

```
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: unitOfWork.Context.Products.ToList();  is called from GetAllProducts() which is called from GetAllProductsTest, and debugger show the same when I stop it at unitOfWork.Context.Products.ToList(); line.

Comment: So `unitOfWork.Context.Products` is showing 2 elements - but when you call `ToList()` there are 0 returned? Just for the purposes of sanity checking, can you include the `GetAllProducts` method please?

Comment: Yea, that's right. Here is the method.         public List<Product> GetAllProducts()
        {
            return unitOfWork.Context.Products.ToList();
        }

Comment: What about `unitOfWork` then? Are you sure it is being assigned as part of the constructor? Is there any other part of your `SalesService` that may remove items or reassign `unitOfWork` an empty of list? Basically, what I'm asking, what else references `unitOfWork` within that class?

Comment: Well, if I pass context which uses the real database in this line unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(context); then rows from database are returned and test passes. When I pass Effort context it is like I wrote in post. So it is something about Effort, there shouldnt be problems in SalesService.